# Using Unity with Windows Azure: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, unity-container, azure-sql-database

I am currently developing an ASP.NET MVC application that uses Unity for the IoC container.  The solution is deployed to Windows Azure using a SQL Azure backend and implments Azure Caching.

After deploying the app to Windows Azure everything seems to work fine.  But then after a few requests I get the error `"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"`.

For example, if I browse to the site and repeatedly initiate an AJAX POST (e.g. autocomplete input) request it will work fine for the first few requests, but then crash out (by means of displaying a HTTP 500 error in the Chrome Dev Tools console).  Then if I try and fresh the page I get the sockets error until the app is restart or the pool is recycled.

Even if I flick between pages I get the same error after a while, i.e. it's not just isolated to the AJAX request. The AJAX request is just the quickest way to replicate the issue.

I'm wondering if the error `An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MySite.Web.MVC.Controllers.LocationsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]` in the stack trace is a red herring because the ILocationCacheService mapping used by the controller is being resolved by Unity. The AJAX request works for the first few times so it definitely resolves the mapping.

Everything works fine locally, or at least I can't replicate the error.

**Stack Trace**

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.

    An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

    Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

    Source Error: 

    An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

    Stack Trace: 


    [SocketException (0x271d): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions]
       System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoMultipleAddressConnectCallback(Object result, MultipleAddressConnectAsyncResult context) +1847654
       System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoDnsCallback(IAsyncResult result, MultipleAddressConnectAsyncResult context) +34
       System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(String host, Int32 port, AsyncCallback requestCallback, Object state) +271
       Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketConnectionFactory.BeginConnect(String host, Int32 port, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, TimeSpan timeout) +469
       Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.TcpClientChannelFactory.BeginConnect(String host, Int32 port, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +119
       Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.TcpClientChannel.ConnectAsync() +368
       Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketClientChannel.TryGetTcpChannelUntilTimeout(TcpClientChannel clientChannel, ITcpChannel& chnl) +41
       Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketClientChannel.Send(EndpointID endpoint, IVelocityRequestPacket packet) +188
       Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketClientChannel.Send(EndpointID endpoint, ICreateMessage message) +112
       Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SimpleSendReceiveModule.Send(EndpointID endpoint, RequestBody request, Int32 retries) +73
       Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SimpleSendReceiveModule.SendMsgAndWait(EndpointID endpt, RequestBody reqMsg, TimeSpan requestTimeout, IRequestTracker& tracker) +428
       Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketClientProtocol.SendMessage(EndpointID endPt, RequestBody request) +52
       Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.EstablishConnection(IEnumerable`1 servers, RequestBody request, Func`3 sendMessageDelegate, DataCacheReadyRetryPolicy retryPolicy) +253
       Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.<>c__DisplayClass5.<Initialize>b__2(RequestBody req) +83
       Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketClientProtocol.SendReceive(IVelocityRequestPacket request, Func`2 delegate, EndpointID& destination) +34
       Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketClientProtocol.Initialize(IEnumerable`1 servers) +367
       Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.GetCache(String cacheName, CreateNewCacheDelegate cacheCreationDelegate, DataCacheInitializationViaCopyDelegate initializeDelegate) +400
       Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.GetCache(String cacheName) +61
       Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.GetDefaultCache() +11
       MySite.Services.Cache.Implementations.LocationCacheService..ctor(ILocationService locationService) +64
       lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +176
       Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +35
       Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +10
       Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +196
       Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +193
       Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) +113
       Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context) +48
       lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +107
       Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +35
       Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +10
       Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +196
       Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +193
       Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) +165

    [ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "MySite.Web.MVC.Controllers.LocationsController", name = "(none)".
    Exception occurred while: Calling constructor MySite.Services.Cache.Implementations.LocationCacheService(MySite.Services.Interfaces.ILocationService locationService).
    Exception is: SocketException - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
    -----------------------------------------------
    At the time of the exception, the container was:

      Resolving MySite.Web.MVC.Controllers.LocationsController,(none)
      Resolving parameter "locationCacheService" of constructor MySite.Web.MVC.Controllers.LocationsController(MySite.Services.Cache.Interfaces.ILocationCacheService locationCacheService)
        Resolving MySite.Services.Cache.Implementations.LocationCacheService,(none) (mapped from MySite.Services.Cache.Interfaces.ILocationCacheService, (none))
        Calling constructor MySite.Services.Cache.Implementations.LocationCacheService(MySite.Services.Interfaces.ILocationService locationService)
    ]
       Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) +329
       Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name, ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides) +15
       Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.Resolve(IUnityContainer container, Type t, ResolverOverride[] overrides) +18
       Unity.Mvc4.UnityDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType) +67
       System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +41

    [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MySite.Web.MVC.Controllers.LocationsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
       System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +178
       System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +77
       System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +66
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +191
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
       System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
       System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: found a similar thread and it seems to be like a bug .. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/bbfca2cd-e214-422c-b7b7-e4bafb090b7a/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissions

Comment: I stumbled across that thread too and tried the proposed solution, but unfortunately it didn't work for me.

Comment: This issue seems to be isolated to the Windows Azure Cache.  If I bypass the caching layer and go straight to the service layer from the controller everything seems to be okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue using connection pooling for cache with `maxconnectionstoserver="1"`. Here is the web.config setting for the `datacacheclient` section:

`<dataCacheClient name="default" isCompressionEnabled="true"  maxConnectionsToServer="1" connectionPool="true" useLegacyProtocol="false">`